# JQuery Flotcharts Line chart - highlight particular series

Tags: jquery, flot, linechart

Is there a possibility to highlight particular lines (not points, but whole series) on jQuery Flotchart? 
If no direct possibility, maybe someone has it's own snippets on this?

Would be much appreciated.

Edit1: Under "Highlight" i mean at least - changing thickness of a line.

Comment: Give **[this](http://www.flotcharts.org/plugins/)** a shot. Maybe you can find what you want.

Comment: Already tried this one. But now i see an animation plugin that I missed before :) I'll try to get on it. Thanks for a tip, will post right after try.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't suit my needs. It only allows to animate line drawing by keyframes (not changing certain line properties).

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I did it on a recent project.  This will "dim" the lines not clicked on (set opacity to 0.1).  Clicking on nothing will bring all series back to 1.0 opacity:

```
$("#container").bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) {
    var re = re = /\(([0-9]+,[0-9]+,[0-9]+)/;
    var opacity = 1;
    var seriesIdx = -1;
    // note which item is clicked on
    if (item) {
        seriesIdx = item.seriesIndex;
        opacity = 0.1;
    }
    // loop all the series and adjust the opacity 
    var modSeries = 
    $.map(somePlot.getData(),function(series,idx){
        if (idx == seriesIdx){
           series.color = 'rgba(' + re.exec(series.color )[1] + ',' + 1 + ')';
        } else {
            series.color = 'rgba(' + re.exec(series.color )[1] + ',' + opacity + ')';
        }
       return series;
    });
    // reload the series and redraw
    somePlot.setData(modSeries);
    somePlot.draw();
});
```

This produces (fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wLLd6/)):

[image]

This should be pretty easy to extend to `lineWidth` if desired.